# How to correctly overload arithmetic operator so that "3" + "4" can be "7" in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I overloaded + with

```
string operator+(string a, string b);
```

it works when I do this:

```
string a = "3";
string b = "4";
cout << a + b;
```

However when I do this, it fails and with error message: invalid operand to binary expression(const char * and const char* )

```
cout << "3" + "4";
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks for reply, I see why there is an error, I shouldn't overload operator in c++ which operand is built-in type.

Comment: Use another language (you may have to build your own language) because C++ won't allow overloading operator that takes no class or enumeration type as its operand.

Comment: There's already an overloaded operator for `"3" + "4";` regarding `std::string`, you might get conflicts.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overload an operator unless you make at least one of the arguments a user defined type, so what you ask is impossible. However, the nearest you could come to that syntax is to perhaps use user defined literals. In C++14, the `s` suffix is defined to create a `std::string`.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::cout << "3"s + "4"s;
```

If you can't use C++14, but can use C++11, then you can define your own literal suffix.

```
std::string operator""_s (const char* cs, size_t)
{
    return std::string(cs);
}
```

Comment: You still can't make your own overload of `operator+` for `std::string` (so this code gives `"34"`, not `"7"` as OP requested), one of the arguments must be a literal that evaluates to your own type